# unable to locate config.rb in an existing project

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm currently in the process of learning sass and compass. I have installed compass successfully into my system. I have an existing sass project to which I have installed compass. The code I have used:
`compass install compass` after switching over to the sass project directory. I need to configure the `config.rb` file. Where do I find it in my project? I am using compass version 1.0.3 (Polaris). My OS is Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: The config.rb file is created in the directory where you executed the command.

Comment: @gyan, as you mentioned, the config.rb is in the directory where the command was executed. But this is only when I create a new compass project. I am not finding it in my existing project to which I have added  compass.

Comment: Actually, for compass config.rb is created when you install the project. So, even though you do not have the same for the project you want to install - It will be there as soon as you install it. Problem is that, it is created in the current directory, so it will depend on the directory, from which the install command was executed. So, you can generate it anywhere and even can place anywhere you wish.

Comment: @gyan Can I copy the `config.rb` into another project or is it project specific?

Comment: Yes you can.. Just make sure that you cross check the settings and do any adjustment required.

Comment: Thanks. Found it. Compass working to my specifics now.